# C# overloaded constructors

Tags: c#, constructor

I am having trouble writing an overloaded constructor for this below. This is what I was asked to do. Create an overloaded constructor for the Plane class that takes three Points as inputs. Name these inputs pointU, pointV, and pointW.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Geometry
{
    public class Plane
    {
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        //                                           PRIVATE INSTANCE VARIABLES
        private Point u;
        private Point v;
        private Point w;

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        //                                                         CONSTRUCTORS
        public Plane()
        {
            u = new Point();
            v = new Point();
            w = new Point();
        }

        //Overloaded Constructor with 3 Points as inputs
```

Comment: @AMR yeah its homework but a very small chunk of it to a class that I don't even need anymore...

Answer (score 2):

Overloaded means changing the signature of your constructor, not having three instances in your default ctor. 
So

```
   public Plane()
   {
     u=new Point(); v= new Point() ; w=new Point()
   }
```

Should be:

```
public Plane(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3)
{
  u= p1; v = p2; w=p3;
}
```

Comment: What is the first part supposed to mean? It sounds like you're quoting the question, but there is nothing like that there.

Answer (score 2):

This is an overloaded constructor that accepts your 3 Points and assigns them to your class members.

```
public Plane(Point u, Point v, Point w){

                this.u = u;
                this.v = v;
                this.w = w;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To overlaod the constuctor with the 3 points you just have to add the 3 arguments to the constructors signature

Example:

```
public Plane(Point pointU, Point pointV, Point pointW)
{
    u = pointU;
    v = pointV;
    w = pointW;
}
```